# Obtaining a value from inside a def()

Tags: python, histogram, user-defined-functions

I have defined a function to plot a histogram. Inside this function I am doing some analysis of the data which I obtain from 2 clicks on the figure.

My code is below:

```
def hist_maker():
     heights,edges = np.histogram(data, 1000)
     edges = edges[:-1]+(edges[1]-edges[0])

     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ax.plot(edges,heights)                                              # plot histogram
     plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
     ax.set(title=titl, xlabel='ADC Value(DN/40)', ylabel='Frequency')

     point1, point2 = fig.ginput(2)                      # get input from 2 clicks on figure

     ax.axvspan(point1[0], point2[0], color='red', alpha=0.5)   # paint selected area in red

     mask = (edges>point1[0]) & (edges<point2[0])

     # calculate which values are selected and display mean
     fig.text(0.2,0.84,'Mean: ' + str((sum(edges[mask]*heights[mask])/sum(heights[mask]))))     

     mean = sum(edges[mask]*heights[mask])/sum(heights[mask])

     mean_noise = edges[heights.argmax() # Find the x value corresponding to the max y value

     fig.text(0.2,0.8,'Std: ' + str(g))
```

What's actually going on inside the function all works fine. But, for example from the code if I wanted to use the caculated `mean_noise` at some point later on in the code, I get an error which says that mean noise is not defined (which is right because it isn't defined outside of the function)

So my question is how to extract the value of mean_noise that I calculate automatically when I have defined hist_maker so that I can use it later on?

One way around this is to get rid of the function hist_maker and just repeat the code inside for each histogram I am plotting which I'm sure would work. But as I am plotting multiple histograms I thought it would be easier to define a function and then just keep calling that for each histogram.

Comment: return mean_noise or have it be a global variable (declared outside of the function scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution - the first line of your function should be:

```
global mean_noise
```

If you then run (outside the function):

```
hist_maker()
print(mean_noise)
```

The print should work.  If you reversed the order of those two lines, you'll get a `NameError`.

Note, though, this is generally not considered good programming.  The generally considered better solution would be to `return mean_noise` at the end of your function.

Comment: Using global mean_noise works and does allow me to use that later on in the code. However, the return mean_noise does not. Let me just check that I am using it right. With the code in my question, all I do is add return mean_noise at the end, and whenever I use the function it should print the value? If that is correct then, a) it does not print the value when i try and b)  it would just print a number and not actually allow me to use it later on

Comment: You would add `return mean`, and then in your code that USES the function, you'd write `mean_noise = hist_maker()`